# Laravel Multi-auth check if user logged in and hide/show navigation tab

Tags: laravel-5

I am using the Laravel multi-auth for multiple users.
I have frontend controller for the public access where no login is required. I want to check there if the user is logged in. If so I want to hide Login nav and show Home/Dashboard nav link which on click should redirect users to his dashboard.
How can I check this in front-end controller/view? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

I have following guards:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'university' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'universities',
    ],

    'school' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'schools',
    ],

    'student' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'students',
    ],
],
```

Model:

```
    <?php

namespace Modules\Student\Http\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Student extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'student';

    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'remember_token'];

    public function applications()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("Modules\Student\Http\Models\Application", 'student_id');
    }

    public function languages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("Modules\Student\Http\Models\StudentLanguage", 'student_id');
    }

    public function certificates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("Modules\Student\Http\Models\StudentCertificate", 'student_id');
    }

    public function educations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("Modules\Student\Http\Models\StudentEducation", 'student_id');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    <?php
namespace Modules\Student\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Modules\Admin\Http\Models\Country;
use Modules\Student\Http\Models\Student;
use Modules\Student\Http\Models\Application;
use Modules\Student\Http\Models\StudentCertificate;
use Modules\Student\Http\Models\StudentLanguage;
use Modules\Student\Http\Models\StudentDocument;
use Modules\Student\Http\Models\StudentEducation;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class StudentController extends Controller
{
    protected $redirectTo = '/student';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:student');
    }

    public function index()
    {
       return view('student::dashboard');
    }

    public function profileForm()
    {
        $countries = Country::get(['id', 'country_name'])->toArray();
        $student = Student::with('languages')
            ->with('certificates')
            ->with('educations')
            ->with('educations.country')
            ->with('ducuments')
            ->find(Auth::User()->id);
        $student->countries = $countries;
        $student->docsGroup = $student->ducuments->groupBy('doc_type');
        return view('student::student_profile')
            ->withStudent($student);
    }

    public function deleteEducation($id)
    {
        $language = StudentEducation::find($id);
        if($language->delete()){
            return 'success';
        }
    }

    public function addCertificate(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'certificate_name'            => 'required',
            'certificate_score'            => 'required',
        ]);

        $certificate = new StudentCertificate();
        $certificate->student_id           = Auth::id();
        $certificate->certificate_name        = $request->certificate_name;
        $certificate->score                   = $request->certificate_score;
        if($certificate->save()){
            Session::flash('success', 'New certificate added successfully!');
            return redirect()->route('student.profile');
        };
        Session::flash('success', 'Some error occured while addeding certificate!');
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput()->with('tab', ['basic_info']);;
    }
}
```

And this is my controller where I want to check if any student/admin.. logged  in or not:

```
 <?php

namespace Modules\Student\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Modules\Admin\Http\Models\Degree;
use Modules\Admin\Http\Models\ProgramCategory;
use Modules\University\Http\Models\Program;
use Modules\University\Http\Models\Scholarship;
use Modules\University\Http\Models\University;
use Modules\Admin\Http\Models\Country;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class FrontendController extends Controller
{
//    public function __construct()
//    {
//        $this->middleware('auth:student');
//    }


    public static function GetSearchAttributes()
    {
        $country_ids = University::where([
            ['status', '=', 'active'],
            ['id', '>', '0']
        ])
            ->get(['country_id'])
            ->pluck('country_id')
            ->toArray();

        $countries = Country::orderBy('country_name', 'asc')
            ->whereIn('id', $country_ids)
            ->get(['id', 'country_name'])
            ->toArray();

        $categories = ProgramCategory::orderBy('category_name', 'ASC')
            ->with('ProgramsCount')
            ->where([
                ['status', '=', 'active'],
                ['parent_id', '=', null]
            ])
            ->get(['category_name', 'id'])
            ->toArray();

        $degrees = Degree::orderBy('degree_name', 'asc')
            ->where('status', '=', 'active')
            ->get(['degree_name', 'id'])
            ->toArray();

        $searchAttr['countries'] = $countries;
        $searchAttr['categories'] = $categories;
        $searchAttr['degrees'] = $degrees;
        $searchAttr = (object) $searchAttr;
        return $searchAttr;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $logos = University::orderBy('id', 'ASC')
            ->where([
                ['status', '=', 'active']
            ])
            ->limit(8)
            ->get();
        return view('student::index')->withLogos($logos);
    }
```

Comment: @if(Auth::user())

Comment: I already tried this but not working. I have multiple guards as: "'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'student' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'students',
        ],
    ],"  and I am using nwidart package and making student namespace is my default one.

Comment: could you please show us your login code?? and some code where you can access user id of logged in user, you table for multi auth, model

Comment: `code` public function login(Request $request)
    {        $this->validate($request, [....]);
        if(Auth::guard('university')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)){
            return redirect()->intended(route('university.dashboard'));
        }
        Session::flash('failed', 'Login credential incorrect!');
        return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }

Comment: please update your question with this information

Comment: and I am accessing logged in user as: `code` class StudentController extends Controller
{
    protected $redirectTo = '/student';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:student');
    }public function profileForm()
    {
        $countries = Country::get(['id', 'country_name'])->toArray();
        $student = Student::with('languages')
            ->with('certificates')
            ->with('educations')
            ->with('educations.country')
            ->with('ducuments')
            ->find(Auth::User()->id);

Comment: please add this information in your question and update it

Comment: check my answer, you will get some idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `check()`

```
@if (Auth::guard('student')->check())
   ///show link for student
@elseif(Auth::guard('admin')->check())
   //show link for admin
@else
   ///show login
@endif
```

Do this for other `guards` too. See [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-get-logged-in-user-data-for-multiple-authentication?page=0) for better understanding.

Comment: Great @Sohel0415. It works like charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: glad it helps you and don't forget to upvote as it may help others :)